# Extract text from HTML files and store in SQLite using Java

Tags: java, sqlite, web-crawler

I have 500 HTML files stored on my computer and I wish to extract the title and description from all those files and store it in my SQLite database(using java if possible). Is there any simple way of doing this?

Came across a couple tools like Crawler4j and JSoup and they seemed to be complicated enough to go over my head...

Comment: So, you mean that [two lines of code](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) are complicated?

Comment: Thank you.. for making me sound stupid :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple regular expressions

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Assuming your non-html does not contain any < or > and that your input string is correctly structured.

if the input string were SomethingAnother Thing, then the above would result in SomethingAnother Thing.

In a situation where multiple tags are expected, we could do something like:

```
String target = someString.replaceAll("(?i)<td[^>]*>", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

This replaces the HTML with a single space, then collapses whitespace, and then trims any on the ends.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite library for HTML handling in Java is the [one written by Henri Sivonen](https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/).

After parsing as DOM tree you may apply XPath search or XSL transformations as you please.
Or you'll place a simple SAX handler to extract/collect the desired texts.

But always keep in mind [if tool-sharpening is worth the time](https://xkcd.com/1205/) ...